# Change "winword" in run dialog from MS Word 2007 to 2010

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, run-dialog

I have both MS Word 2007 and 2010 (trial version). When I go to `Start -> Run` and enter `winword`, MS Word 2007 opens.

I want to change it, so MS Word 2010 opens by default. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

1. Open `regedit`.
2. Locate the following key:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Winword.exe
   ```
3. Change the value of `(Default)` to the location of the Word 2010 executable.
4. Change the value of `Path` to the location of the Word 2010 executable's folder.
5. Close `regedit`.

Comment: how do i find the path of my MS word 2010.

Comment: These are the path values I got on checking the RightClick->Properties of my MS Word 2010 in Start Menu:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Virtualization Handler\ AND
C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\VIRTUA~1\CVH.EXE

Comment: That sounds right. Just try it out and keep a copy of the original values.